# Text_field_tag default value if params are empty?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want my `text_field_tag` to have the current date as a default value if the params for params[:date] is empty, here is my code at the moment:

```
<%= text_field_tag :end, params[:end]  %>
```

i want somthing like: `<%= text_field_tag :end, if params[:end] then use this value else show current date  %>`

thank you

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can simply use the "or" operator.  If params[:end] is empty, it'll use Time.now.

```
<%= text_field_tag :end, (params[:end] or Time.now)  %>
```

Comment: You may use `||` operator instead of `or` in newer versions.